# Why there is no "Sharing Options" on cinnamon on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, samba, file-sharing, cinnamon

I've installed latest Cinnamon on Ubuntu 12.04, everything is perfect, except sharing files and folders. When I'm trying to share any files/folders by right-clicking the files/folders, surprisingly there is no "sharing options" field on the menu. Why it's not there? How can get that option back?
[image]

[image: Screenshots of missing sharing options]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "Sharing Options" option in the context menu in Cinnamon is provided by `nautilus-share`.

So, first check if you have installed this package with next command in [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal):

```
whereis nautilus-share
```

If you don't have it installed, you can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-share
```

If your default file browser is not Nautilus and is Nemo, use next commands instead:

```bsh
whereis nemo-share                  #to check if is installed
sudo apt-get install nemo-share     #to install
```

Comment: natilus-share is installed. Here is the output : 

fahim@fahim-NF208:~$ whereis nautilus-share
nautilus-share: /usr/share/nautilus-share
fahim@fahim-NF208:~$ sudo apt-get install nautilus-share
[sudo] password for fahim: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
nautilus-share is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
fahim@fahim-NF208:~$

Comment: Thanks for your help. Problem is solved. Actually nemo-share package was missing and after installing that everything is alright now.

Comment: @tuxtu Ah... you should say that you are using nemo. I will edit my answer so the question to have a valid answer for other future visitors.

Comment: Yes. It'll better if I said that before, but thanks to you that actually you detected the problem. I've just replaced "nautilus" with "nemo".

Comment: don't forget to logout n login!

Answer (score 3):

Cinnamon use Nemo as file manager and it use `nemo-share` package for sharing files/folders. To isntall that I issued the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install nemo-share
```

Then restart your PC and see the problem is solved.

Comment: You may wrong with "*Cinnamon use Nemo as file manager*". I've installed Cinnamon and still my default browser is Nautilus.

Comment: Nemo is the official file manager for the Linux Mint operating system running the Cinnamon desktop. Please take look here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nemo_%28file_manager%29

Comment: In Linux Mint. I use Ubuntu and for this I said that you may wrong.